# the length of cycles in a $2$-connected simple gragh

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple $2$-connected graph and $C$ is a cycle in $G$ satisfies:

For any vertex $v$ of $C$,there exists at least one vertex $u\in V(G)\backslash V(C)$ adjacent with $v$.

Is it true that there must exists a cycle in $G$ which is longer than $C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick reduction.  Hopefully someone else can finish it off.  Since $G$ is 2-connected, it has an ear-decomposition starting with the cycle $C$.  Next, when building the ear-decomposition, for as long as possible always choose ears $P$ such that both ends of $P$ are in $C$ and $P$ has two edges.  Now consider the last ear $P'$.  If $P'$ is just an edge $e$, then $G \setminus e$ is 2-connected and we win by induction.  Thus, $P'$ has at least two edges.  If $P'$ has at least 3 edges, then let $G'$ be the graph obtained from $G$ by replacing $P'$ by a path of length 2.  Note that $G'$ is 2-connected, and every vertex in $C$ still has a neighbour outside of $C$ in $G'$.  Thus, by induction, $G'$ and hence $G$ has a cycle longer than $C$.  Thus, $P'$ has exactly two edges.  If at least one end of $P'$ is not in $C$, then by replacing $P'$ with a single edge, we win by induction.  Thus, both ends of $P'$ are in $C$.  Therefore, *every* ear is a $C$-path with two edges. We can thus colour the edges of $C$ red and replace each ear with a blue edge.  We now have a graph $G''$ with $V(G'')=V(C)$, and where every vertex is incident to a blue edge.  I think it should be easy to show that such a graph has a cycle longer than $C$ (red edges have length 1, and blue edges have length 2).

Comment: Tony Huynh,Thank you for your help!But I can not go any futher!I am still thinking about it.

Comment: Hello,Tony Huynh,I want to proof the simplest case:$C$ is $2n$-cycle and there are $n$ ears on $C$ in all such that (as you said)every ear is a $C$-path with two edges and every two ears do not have common vertex.So every vertex of $C$ is a end of an ear.But I can not proof it or give a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof for the simplest case, as you define it in your comment to Tony's answer.
In this simplest case you essentially have a 3-regular graph that has a Hamiltonian cycle and you ask whether another Hamiltonian cycle exists. This is called Smith's theorem, see

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmithsNetworkTheorem.html

or

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma#Exchange_graphs

I also think that every other case reduces to this one, through some not very interesting case analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,domotorp.The simplest case had been answered by Tony Huynh,see my another question:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/145531/an-interesting-conjecture-about-even-cycle.

Comment: I see, maybe next time it is a good idea to update your question/put a link to the next question you pose. So what is the question left here?

Comment: Yes,I should have updated my question.It is my negligence.